# Server application that obtains user credentials and access network services using those credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, iis-7.5

I am a little new to IIS and am not 100% sure that this is possible. I am writing a C# application that needs to get the users network credentials and then connect to TFS using those credentials. I am able to do one or the other, but never both at the same time.

To obtain the users credentials that is accessing the site I have to use NetworkService as the AppPool's Identity with a call to `credentials = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. The reason i need to get the users username is to find out which items they have permission to access in TFS later using `item.VersionControlServer.GetEffectivePermissions(credentials, item.ServerItem)`.

To connect to TFS I have to put the users credentials as the AppPool's Identity or give NetworkService access to TFS (not something that is going to happen) with a call to `RegisteredTfsConnections.GetConfigurationServer("server");`

I either need a way to use the credentials obtained by the application to access TFS, or I need a way to create a new user that has "Network Service like" abilities to get the user's credentials and then give this user access to TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I didn't know and recently found out is that if you set IIS to run as a user, you can enable Windows Authentication in the IIS > (Select Site) > Authentication settings and use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to obtain the current logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially hitting something called 'double hop authentication' and you will not be able to proceed without making sure that you have a Kerberos token.

Its quite complicated to [configure Kerberos](http://www.phishthis.com/2009/10/24/how-to-configure-ad-sql-and-iis-for-two-hop-kerberos-authentication-2/) but once you have it up and running your code will just start working. The only other way to achieve this is to actually have the users username and password.